# We name everything

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Hint: We name everything. And then I mean **everything**. E V E R Y T H I N G. Hard to **sum** it all up.

Well, have a go at it:

**13/59-21/18   11/36/15/19(2)/14   12/1/19/37   17/17(2)/53/36(2)/31/43  32/5/29(2)/40  29/21/9/31.  40/31/9/43   43/5/19/40/5/19/13/5   9/43  13/15/18/36(2)/17(2)/5/40/5/17(2)53  17/19(2)/1/18/18/1/40/9/13/1/17(2),  1/17(2)/40/31/15/21/17/31  1/19(2)/13/31/1/9/13  9/19  59-21/15/19(2)/14  13/31/15/9/13/5.  32/5/19(2)/53  18/9/43/17(2)/5/1/14/9/19/17  11/15/19(2)  14/5/13/15/14/5/19(2)/43,  40/31/5  43/31/15/19(2)/40/5/43/40  36(2)/1/19/17/19(2)/1/18  13/19(2)/5/1/40/5/14.**

Sorry if it's a bit messy, tried to make the spaces bigger but it didn't work. But you can just copy/paste it over to a document and spread it out there if you want. Good luck :)

Comment: Slash missing in second row semi-last "word"at the end?

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

> Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz.
>  This sentence is completely
>  grammatical, although archaic in
>  word choice. Very misleading for
>  decoders, the shortest pangram
>  created.

Where:

> As M Oehm pointed out in a comment, each letter is the sum of the letters in the spelled out name (e.g. b = "bee" = 2+5+5 = 12).  So:
>
>  a=a=1
>  b=bee=12
>  c=cee=13
>  d=dee=14
>  e=e=5
>  f=ef=11
>  g=gee=17
>  h=aitch=31 (mistake? should be 36)
>  i=i=9
>  j=jay=36
>  k=kay=37
>  l=el=17(2)
>  m=em=18
>  n=en=19
>  o=o=15
>  p=pee=36(2) (mistake? should be 26)
>  q=cue=29
>  r=ar=19(2)
>  s=ess=43
>  t=tee=40 (mistake? should be 30)
>  u=u=21
>  v=vee=32
>  w=double-u=59-21
>  x=ex=29(2)
>  y=wye=53
>  z=zee=31 (mistake? should be 36)

And the way I solved it:

> I treated it like a normal cryptogram, and solved the word "grammatical" first, since very few words have that form (although I first tried "overreached" but that didn't work out).  After I got "grammatical", a lot of other words just fell into place, although the first sentence was not helpful at all for obvious reasons.

Comment: Good work! For what it's worth, I think the mistake is rather with the h, which should probebly be 41. The "sum" in the puzzle is a hint: rot13(Gur pbqrf ner gur NM fhzf bs gur yrggref jura fcryyrq bhg: [n, orr, prr, ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet) Ohg V unir: nvgpu: 41, crr: 26, grr: 30, mrq: 35 be mrr: 36.)